# how to get Email from server through javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the email from Geotab.com, is there anybody who know about how to get email from server using api.**Access email from server using api in jquery or javascript**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you use the GeoTab API in Javascript:

https://geotab.github.io/sdk/software/guides/using-in-javascript

However, I don't see a way to access emails with the API. I didn't expect that either. Emails are served by a mailserver, not by an API. Obviously. An API can do many things, and the GeoTab API is no exception.

**The question is:** Do you actually want the emails, as emails, in which case you shouldn't be using the API, or can, what you wanted to do with the emails, be done with the API? (To answer this you have to read the documentation)